# Using Tor and IRC

Tags: irc, tor

How can I use [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/) with IRC? I have noticed that some networks block Tor. How true is that?

I have a problem with flashing my IP adderss whenever I join a channel. Freenode provides a convenient `unaffiliated` tag for registered users that lets them hide their IP address. But not all networks provide this.

I have noticed many users with the :

```
debian-tor@gateway/tor-sasl/<nick>
```

on Freenode. How do I get one?

Comment: You can script your client to delay joins till after you get mode x (I think that's set when your unaffiliated address is set).

Comment: If the network supports it, SASL is a more reliable method than "delaying joins".

Answer (score 5):

There is no definite answer. Each network has its own rules regarding Tor and proxy servers in general.

---

For Freenode, you have to:

1. Set up your IRC client for SASL authentication ([KB article](https://freenode.net/kb/answer/sasl));
2. Connect to the Freenode hidden service ([KB article](https://freenode.net/kb/answer/chat)).

The Tor cloak will be applied automatically. **However**, you mentioned that you *already have* a generic `unaffiliated/*` cloak, so Tor should not be necessary on Freenode.

(Nevertheless, configuring SASL is a good idea, to ensure that your cloak – Tor or not – gets applied *before* joining channels.)

---

Alternatively, you can connect to IRC through a (proxy) server. Some people rent their own VPS and configure it as a proxy; others settle with an account on a public "shell server".

Whichever of these you choose, it is very easy to tunnel IRC over a generic SSH 'shell' connection.

Some people prefer to use *bouncers* instead – it's a kind of IRC proxy server that, in addition of hiding your actual address, allows your session to stay online 24/7 even if you disconnect from the bouncer. (IMHO, not much point in that, unless you want to keep complete logs of a channel.)

Comment: Bouncers hearken back to dialup days when some would dial-in to a Unix box to access the Internet.  Having a bouncer running on such a box meant that you would get channel scoop even if your phone wasn't tied up.  Still useful today because IRC doesn't support presence information, if a person doesn't respond right away they might see your message several hours (or even days) later.

Comment: @ultrasawblade: Presence information, as in `/away`?